# Error message on failed backup of file already deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, notifications, backup, error-messages-for

I am using a google apps script that I found on stack overflow to do a daily back up of files time-based.
Now I have deleted a few of those files and get an email from apps-scripts-notifications@goggle.com that the script has failed to finish successfully.

Using this code:

```js
// Abhijeet Chopra
// 26 February 2016
// Google Apps Script to make copies of Google Sheet in specified destination folder

function makeCopy() {
  // generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");  
  // gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;  
  // gets the destination folder by their ID. REPLACE xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with your folder's ID that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ysgERhjmrnq5Uzb9Lu7CtqOWccVTHyVj");  
  // gets the current Google Sheet file
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())  
  // makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
  file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

The error message is *Authorization is required to perform that action.*

As the file is not in my Trash folder on my Google Drive anymore, I don't how to turn off that attempts to backup a file that shouldn't exist any more. I also couldn't find any active triggers any more.

I really appreciate some input! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your situation. The function you shared makes a copy of the file the script is bound to. If the container file does not exist anymore, this function should not exist anymore either. What's more, the trigger itself should not exist anymore, if your project doesn't exist anymore. Are you sure this is the function you're using to make file backups? If that's the case, I guess you have a trigger for each file?

Comment: I am using exactly this code, only changed the folder ID. The trigger was time based to create a copy every day at 5 pm. I cannot see any of these triggers left and also the files aren't in my trash folder any more. Do you have any hints where I can check if some rest is still in existence?

Comment: These triggers don't show up in `My Triggers` in your [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/)? (select **Edit > All your triggers** to get there). If it's still sending notifications, you should be able to find it there - maybe the project name won't appear and it will say `Disabled` (by the way, having a trigger for each file is really inefficient, you could have a single trigger in a standalone script that would make a backup of all your files instead).

Comment: I have checked my list of triggers and found some in status DISABLED, then deleted all of them. Unfortunately I still receive the emails with these error messages: Authorization is required to perform that action. (line 14, file "Code")

Comment: Are you sure the triggers were not created by another account?